# How do I make radiobuttonFors selectable by its text?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, radiobuttonfor

I am stumped by the following:

Here is my code:

```
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <% foreach (string Item in HR_Applications.Helper.GetOrdersForDay(DayOfWeek.Monday))
                       { %>
                    <%= Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MondayOrder,Item) %>
                    <%: Item %>
                    <br />
                    <%} %>
                </div>
```

This code renders my radiobuttons just fine. The problem that I have here is that I am worried users cannot select the radiobuttons by its text, but must click the buttons itself. How do I make the radiobuttons selectable by its text?

This control must be used: business requirement set out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the id of your `RadioButton` and use a `label` with the `for` attribute.

```
<label for="<%:Item.Name%>"><%:Item.Name%></label>
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MondayOrder,Item, new {id = Item.Name}) %>
```

**Update**

If you're not able to use a unique value from your model for the Ids then use a counter to keep track and append it to your Ids:

```
<% 
int counter = 0;
foreach ( [...])
{
   <label for="<%:Item.Name + counter%>"><%:Item.Name%></label>
[...]
counter++;

}
%>
```

Comment: Just a question, how do I handle duplicate values?

Comment: Always selects the first item available if duplicates exist

Comment: You can create a counter in your loop and incriment it before appending it to your ID. I'll add that to my answer.